# Screen position changed after changing resolution using xrandr

Tags: resolution, ubuntu-14.04, display-settings, xrandr

I just got a new ubuntu 14.04 PC at work (I am already using another Windows 7 PC) and found that it had a low resolution (1024x768) set by default, while the ideal resolution for my monitor is 1280x1024 (that is what my Windows PC shows). I learnt about 'xrandr' and decided to add a new mode as directed [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html).

Now, the real issue is that the resolution has changed to 1280x1024 but there is an apparent shift in the screen position - horizontally towards right about an offset of 1.25 inches and vertically towards up about an offset of 0.125 inches - in ubuntu alone. My Windows PC is just fine. Tried out --auto and --pos options of xrandr but to no avail. I have a feeling I'm missing some feature of xrandr here.

How can I get it back to normal at (0,0) by shifting the position a bit down vertically and a bit left horizontally. Now my screen is positioned at an approximate (100,15)?

**Updates :**

- I tried reverting back to earlier resolution of 1024x768. Then, the screen is back to normal. I mean it is now positioned at (0,0).
- I tried deleting the created new mode using xrandr and creating a fresh new mode. Still it has got the shift to the same degree as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667085/screen-shift-in-ubuntu?rq=1/) and tried the auto-adjust/auto-configure button on my DELL monitor. It appeared to have solved the issue. But when I switched to my Windows 7 PC (I use a KVM switch to toggle between my PCs), I saw that it had affected the positioning there.

So, I played around with Screen Resolution settings in my Windows 7 PC and changed the refresh rate from the default 60Hz to 75 Hz. And Voila! It positioned itself back to normal! Having read in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667085/screen-shift-in-ubuntu?rq=1/) post that it recurs at startup everytime, I tried restarting the system as well as shutting down and turning it on back again too. I can confirm that it is back to normal now.

This has fixed the issue but for the sake of my curiosity I would love to know the mechanics behind this. It would be helpful if someone explained what is the exact reason behind this behavior. It doesn't appear as something that has got to do with xrandr afterall!

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted after 48 hours since when you posted your question by clicking the check mark beside it which changes its color to green.